# Laravel 8 how to parse template variables in string

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string that contains multiple templated variables like this:

```
$str = "Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}";
```

How can I do to extract these variables in an array like this :

```
$array = ['first_name', 'last_name'];
```

Comment: you can make string blade compatible and use string rendering method [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-inline-blade-templates)

Comment: Actually I can't use string blade I have to use this format :/

Comment: then you can write a custom string parser function. maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/samjoshi/a6db0a4a1701b96ed77cfe447057e844) can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to find a regex to detect this pattern and use preg_split() after

Comment: The variables will just be interpolated into the string by PHP, throwing an undefined variable notice if they don't exist, and a deprecation notice either way. What does this have to do with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes when describing the string.

```
$str = 'Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}';
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/s', $str, $output_array);
dd($output_array[1]);
```

Comment: It's possible to get directly the good array without specify `[1]` ?

Comment: @John `0` is the full match. `1` is the first capture group. Each index is a capture group, after the full match which is always `0`. see also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php if you don't want to specify index you can use `end()`

Answer (score 1):

Use explode function example given below:

```
$str = "Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}";
    
$str_to_array = explode("$",$str);
$array = array();
foreach($str_to_array as $data){
    if (str_contains($data, '{')) {
        $array[] = str_replace("}","",str_replace("{","",$data));
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

Comment: Your solution is working. I'm searching for a solution with regex pattern for less code. But your solution is nice. You just have to specify that `str_contains` is for php 8

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression and use `preg_match_all` to find all the ocurrences, like this:

```
<?php
    $pattern = '|\${.*?}|';
    $subject = 'Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}';
    $matches = '';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ${first_name}
            [1] => ${last_name}
        )

)
```

EDIT: To get just the names of the variables, a small modification of the code will make it possible:

```
<?php
    $pattern = '|\${(.*?)}|'; // We added parenthesis making '.*?' a sub-pattern now.
    $subject = 'Hello ${first_name} ${last_name}';
    $matches = '';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ${first_name}
            [1] => ${last_name}
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => first_name
            [1] => last_name
        )
)
```

Now the first element of the result array contains the matched results for the full regex expression, and the second one contains the matched results for the sub-pattern.

Comment: It's a nice solution but how can I do to return only the variable name in the array ? I just need first_name and last_name